# rata die to unix time

Tags: date, elm

I am trying to convert `Date.Date` from the `justinmimbs/date` package to `Time.Posix` from `elm/time` or an integer of milliseconds since UNIX epoch.

my current approach is the following but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
dateToPosixTime : Date.Date -> Time.Posix
dateToPosixTime date =
    Time.millisToPosix (Date.toRataDie date - 719162 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
```

(719162 is the offset of Jan 1, 1970 to Jan 1, 0001)

This seemed to work, but it doesn't give me working results anymore

Another approach:

```
dateToPosixTime : Date.Date -> Time.Posix
dateToPosixTime date =
    Time.millisToPosix ((Date.toRataDie date - epochStartOffset) * (1001 * 60 * 60 * 24) - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
```

Comment: Would be helpful to mention which packages this is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, basically the second approach I described works, if you don't accidentally write `1001 * 60 * 60 * 24` instead of the correct `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`, because one second only has 1000 milliseconds, not 1001.

The working code therefore is:

```
epochStartOffset : Int
epochStartOffset =
    719162


dateToPosixTime : Date.Date -> Time.Posix
dateToPosixTime date =
    Time.millisToPosix ((Date.toRataDie date - epochStartOffset) * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to be unambiguous about *whose* date you're working with (UTC? New York? Nepal?), [justinmimbs/time-extra](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/time-extra/1.1.0/) has a convenient [`partsToPosix` function](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/time-extra/1.1.0/Time-Extra#partsToPosix), making it easy to create an unambiguous function with the signature `Zone -> Date -> Posix`

```
midnightOfDate : Zone -> Date -> Posix
midnightOfDate zone date =
    TE.partsToPosix zone
        { year = Date.year date
        , month = Date.month date
        , day = Date.day date
        , hour = 0
        , minute = 0
        , second = 0
        , millisecond = 0
        }
```

on the Elm repl:

```
> Date.fromRataDie 719163 |> Date.toIsoString
"1970-01-01" : String

> midnightOfDate Time.utc (Date.fromRataDie 719163)
Posix 0 : Time.Posix
```